# Visual Studio 2013 - Slow Extension or Add In - how to find which one?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I have a solution with about 40 projects in it. When I load or unload a project it takes up to 5 minutes and hangs the development environment for the entire time. When I go into safe mode it is about 5s or less. I don't know proc mon very well, but it did show lots of file access outside the project in question.

I'm assuming this is caused by an extension or add in. How do I figure out which one. I have disabled all the ones I can disable but a large proportion of my extensions cannot be disabled. Do I really have to uninstall them all in turn?

Cheers,

James

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to find what module in Visual Studio is currently running when VS hangs from the DevEnv.exe process Properties - Threads tab.

Comment: The guilty thread is devenv.exe!!sIsAssertEtwEnabled. Not sure what it does but it's eating millions of cycles and accessing loads of files. Googling it shows it is a source of loads of performance problems but there doesn't seem to be a single cause. Does anyone know what it does?

Answer (score 0):

DevExpress Assembly Deployment Tool v1.1 with DevExpress 13.2.7

I have discovered why my Visual Studio Environment has been so slow (unusably slow – 10 minutes to do 5 second tasks – locked application for 10 minutes at a time).

Solution is to uninstall VS extension DevExpress Assembly Deployment Tool v1.1.
As detailed here:

https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q570295