# How to see what Visual Studio is actively doing during freeze?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I'm running a Python 2.7 server in Visual Studio 2013 (update 5) with PT4VS, Twisted, and P4V integration (I mention these details because they may be related to the lockup). Periodically Visual Studio freezes (but never goes white like most processes do) and becomes unusable for a minute or so. This is happening several times a day not just for myself but for our entire development team and, of course, it's really annoying.

I tried Googling for a solution but came up dry. What I'd like to know is, is there a way I can see what Visual Studio is doing during this locked time so I can maybe pin down what the issue exactly is.

Comment: That's almost always a problem caused by an add-in.  Disabling them one-by-one until you find the troublemaker is one strategy.  If you know the debugger well then you can usually find out more by starting VS again and using Tools > Attach to Process.  Enable both the native and managed debugging engines.  Might even get it going within one minute :)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26050044/visual-studio-2013-slow-extension-or-add-in-how-to-find-which-one